# why is this not the same: char dog[1000]; and char *dog = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

Tags: c

when I "print" the sizeof(dog) for

```
char dog[1000];// i get size of 1000
char *dog = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));// i get size of 8 ? why?
```

thx

Comment: Because the former is allocated on the stack and the latter is allocated in the heap and is referenced by a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first variable has type `char[1000]` which is an array of 1000 chars.

The second variable has type `char *` which is a pointer. On your system it appears that pointers have a size of 8 (probably because you have 64-bit pointers).

Comment: but isn't "dog" on the 1st one a pointer as well(isn't "char" pointer"?), but on the stack as apposed to the second on the heap?

Comment: @jdl: No. The first one is an array.

Comment: Arrays degrade to pointers, which is why they can be used in much the same ways as pointers. However, `sizeof()` on arrays yields the size of the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

Because `char *dog` is just a single pointer whereas `char dog[1000]` an array of chars.

The important point to note is that `sizeof` `dog[1000]` is determined is known at compile time whereas dynamic array (`char *dog`) is unknown.